# Convertir una lista de listas de números en una lista de listas de números separados por coma

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una serie de listas de listas con esta forma:

```
lista = [[116], [17], [8]]
```

Me gustaría convertirlas en listas de listas donde los números están separadas por comas. Algo así:

```
[[1,1,6], [1,7], [8]]
```

Estoy intentando utilizar la función `split` sin éxito. ¿No hay una manera de hacer esto en una línea? No encuentro duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me sirvió con esto:

```
# entrada = [[116], [17], [8]]
# salida = [[1,1,6], [1,7], [8]]

def dividir_lista(lst):
  return [int(i) for i in str(lst)]

def dividir_lista_de_lista(lst): 
    return [dividir_lista(el[0]) for el in lst] 

# Ejecución de los métodos 
lst = [[116], [17], [8]]
print(dividir_lista_de_lista(lst))
```

`split` no funciona porque este método se usa con cadenas de texto y en este caso no se puede hacer `split` de una lista.

**Actualización**

```
def dividir_lista_anidada(lst):
  return [[int(i) for i in str(el[0])] for el in lst]

# Ejecución del método
lst = [[116], [17], [8]]
print(dividir_lista_anidada(lst))
```